# Policy on duplicates of unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

[This question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/do-these-patients-have-measles-inclusion-body-encephalitis-mibe-and-or-rubella) is the same as [this unanswered question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/analysis-of-cdna-samples-from-brain-with-suspected-measles-inclusion-body-enceph), all the way down to the asker's thoughts.

I suppose it might be the case that a new user is trying to gain reputation by re-asking old questions, but that aside, what is the policy on re-asking old, **unanswered** questions?

I understand that there is value in bringing it to the attention of the community so that it might finally be answered, but at the same time, you're creating a duplicate question.  I think that upvoting/commenting on the original question to bring it to the top of the queue might be a better solution, *unless there is something different about the new question* (such as the inclusion of the asker's thoughts on the matter?).

Is there any official policy in place regarding this situation? I know that duplicate questions in which the original has an upvoted answer are closed, but I am not aware of anything pertaining to unanswered questions.

Comment: In the interests of pointing out duplicate questions, this is related to http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/389/how-similar-must-a-duplicate-question-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicates are duplicates, and duplicates get closed.

Comment: Except I am unable to vote to close, because "the duplicate question does not have at least one upvoted answer."

Comment: It's closed now. You can flag for moderator attention, and one of us will look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The rule that the community can't close questions as a duplicate of an unanswered question has an exception when both questions belong to the same user. Reposting is against the rules, and those reposted questions should be closed.

Now, in this case it is likely the same user, but they appear as different ones. In such cases flagging for moderator attention is the correct action.

Comment: Excellent bit of nuance. Consecutive questions by the same user (especially unregistered ones) can be a problem unto themselves.